# Ajax request is not working php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have asked this earlier but still I wasn't lucky to get it work. Simply I am trying to update profile picture with a default picture when Delete button is clicked and I am trying to use ajax to do this, however whenever I click on the button nothing happens and the picture is not updated. I have tested the php page by itself and it works nicely but the js isn't working so could someone spot what I am doing wrong here?

html

```
<button href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="delete;"  class="btn btn-default delbutt">Delete</button>
```

js

```
function delete()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php?action=delete",
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{  
var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
  $("#phd").fadeOut('slow');
$(".suc_pic").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#msg"));
 }
});
}
```

and here is the php lastly

```
$username = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"]) || isset($_GET["action"]) && !empty($_GET["action"])) 
{
if(isset($_GET["action"]) == "delete") 
{               
$profile = 'default.jpg';
$pp = $db->prepare("update users set profile = ? where username = ?");
echo $db->error;
$pp->bind_param('ss', $profile, $username->username);
$pp->execute();
}
}
else {
echo "Something is wrong. Try again.";
}
```

Comment: in php file, are you enable `session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

POST queries are by default not cached in jQuery ajax (1), so you probably should just use the [`$.post` helper](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead. Also, querystring values are not parsed to the `$_POST` super-global, so your code as-is will always read null from `$_POST["action"]`.

```
function delete(){
    $.post(
        "test.php",
        {
            action: 'delete'
        },
        success: function(response){  
            var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
            $("#phd").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".suc_pic").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#msg"));
         }
    );
}
```

(1) As defined in the API reference:

> Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified
>   options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

Comment: @user3412305 "does not work" is not particularly helpful. Care to elaborate?

Comment: hmmm, when I look in the console it says 'after id missing }' on line 7.. I finally figured it out by setting hidden field and using data. Thanks for the help tho. Finally it turns out the onclick was wrong, cos I was missing ()

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that jQuery AJAX requests should have a `data:` option in there somewhere. Also, I see you're using GET to make the request, but tell jQuery to use POST.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "test.php",
cache: false,
data : {
action : 'delete'
success : function(response)
{
etc...
```

I'm no jQuery expert, but I think that may be your problem. The only other thing I can think of is the success function isn't working properly. Check your F12 menu and post any warnings/errors so we can see it.